# Optimizing a delete... where query with rownum

Tags: oracle, query-optimization, sql-delete, rownum

I'm working with an application that has a large amount of outdated data clogging up a table in my databank. Ideally, I'd want to delete all entries in the table whose reference date is too old:

```
delete outdatedTable where referenceDate < :deletionCutoffDate
```

If this statement were to be run, it would take ages to complete, so I'd rather break it up into chunks with the following:

```
delete outdatedTable where referenceData < :deletionCutoffDate and rownum <= 10000
```

In testing, this works suprisingly slowly. The following query, however, runs dramatically faster:

```
delete outdatedTable where rownum <= 10000
```

I've been reading through multiple blogs and similar questions on StackOverflow, but I haven't yet found a straightforward description of how/whether using rownum affects the Oracle optimizer when there are other Where clauses in the query. In my case, it seems to me as if Oracle checks

```
referenceData < :deletionCutoffDate
```

on every single row, executes a massive Select on all matching rows, and only then filters out the top 10000 rows to return. Is this in fact the case? If so, is there any clever way to make Oracle stop checking the Where clause as soon as it's found enough matching rows?

Comment: Perhaps try asking on the [DBA](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) site - *"Advanced Querying including window-functions, dynamic-sql, **and query-performance**"* is explicitly listed as on-topic there.

Comment: I recommend backup entries you want to keep (into another, new table), then drop table and rename your backup table to original name.

Comment: Is there an index on `deletionCutoffDate`?

Comment: Yes, there's an index on the date.

Answer (score 1):

How about a different approach without so much **DML** on the table. As a permanent solution for future you could go for **table partitioning**.

1. Create a new table with required partition(s).
2. Move ONLY the required rows from your existing table to the new partitioned table.
3. Once the new table is populated, add the required constraints and indexes.
4. Drop the old table.

In future, you would just need to **DROP** the **old partitions**.

**CTAS**(create table as select) is another way, however, if you want to have a new table with partition, you would have to go for exchange partition concept.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should [read about SQL statement's execution plan and learn how to explain in](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E25054_01/server.1111/e16638/ex_plan.htm). It will help you to find answers on such questions.

Generally, one single delete is more effective than several chunked. It's main disadvantage is extremal using of undo tablespace.

If you wish to delete most rows of table, much faster way usially a trick:

```
create table new_table as select * from old_table where date >= :date_limit;
drop table old_table;
rename table new_table to old_table;
... recreate indexes and other stuff ...
```

If you wish to do it more than once, partitioning is a much better way. If table partitioned by date, you can select actual date quickly and you can drop partion with outdated data in milliseconds.

At last, paritioning if a way to dismiss 'deleting outdated records' at all. Sometimes we need old data, and it's sad if we delete it by own hands. With paritioning you can archive outdated partitions outside of the database, but connects them when you need to access old data.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old request, but I'd like to show another approach (also using partitions).

Depending on what you consider old, you could create corresponding partitions (optimally exactly two; one current, one old; but you could just as well make more), e.g.:

```
PARTITION BY LIST ( mod(referenceDate,2) )
(
  PARTITION year_odd VALUES (1),
  PARTITION year_even VALUES (0)
);
```

This could as well be months (Jan, Feb, ... Dec), decades (XX0X, XX1X, ... XX9X), half years (first_half, second_half), etc. Anything circular.

Then whenever you want to get rid of old data, truncate:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable TRUNCATE PARTITION year_even;
```

Answer (score 0):

`delete from your_table
where PK not in
(select PK from your_table where rounum<=...)` -- these records you want to leave